# What is the relationship between theta and size in negative binomial distribution?

Tags: negative-binomial-distribution

In negative binomial regression glm.nb(y~x), I got a parameter theta and two coefficients? And then I want to use dnbinom(x, size, prob, mu, log = FALSE) to calculate the predicted probability.

can anyone show me what is the relationship between theta and size, and how to transfer between these two parameters?

If every point's value in a dataset is expanded two times, how does size or theta change?

Answer (score 6):

The `$theta` from a fitted `glm.nb()` corresponds to the `size` in `dnbinom()`. As a simple example, let's replicate the fitted log-likelihood from scratch. Using the `quine` data from `MASS`:

```
library("MASS")
m <- glm.nb(Days ~ ., data = quine)
logLik(m)
## 'log Lik.' -546.5755 (df=8)
```

And this value of the log-likelihood can be obtained by summing the `dnbinom(..., log = TRUE)` values:

```
sum(dnbinom(quine$Days, mu = fitted(m), size = m$theta, log = TRUE))
## [1] -546.5755
```

Doubling the weight of all observations leaves all parameter estimates (including `theta`) unchanged:

```
quine$weights <- 2      
    m2 <- glm.nb(Days ~ ., data = quine, weights = weights)
    m$theta
## [1] 1.274893
m2$theta
[1] 1.274893
```